# JS AWS S3 public bucket access via makeUnauthenticatedRequest: "Network Failure"?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-s3, network-programming

I am trying to access my public bucket at AWS S3 via:

```
....

<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.4.5.min.js"></script>

....
    const AWS = window.AWS;

    AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';

    let params =
    {
        Bucket: bucketPath,
           Key: fileKey
    }

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.makeUnauthenticatedRequest('getObject', params, function (err, data)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log( data.Body.toString() );
        }
    });
....
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
{
 "message": "Network Failure",
 "code": "NetworkingError",
 "time": "2016-07-08T12:13:34.050Z",
 "region": "us-east-1",
 "hostname": "s3.amazonaws.com",
 "retryable": true
}
```

I guess, the problem could have something to do with the region: I am trying to set eu-central-1, but the error refers to us-east-1 ... what's wrong with my code?

Many thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we cannot assume the constructor can find out the correct region itself, so the correct instantiation of s3 for my region is:

```
let s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'eu-central-1', maxRetries: 15});
```